# How to implement config in AbstractHttpConfigurer's *before* local HttpSecurity code

Tags: spring-security

I'm updating an internal library and applications to Spring Boot 3 (which updated to Spring Security 6).

We have common security configuration which I've updated to implement `AbstractHttpConfigurer` e.g.

```
public class WebberWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<WebberWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, HttpSecurity> {

  public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
      .authorizeHttpRequests()
      .requestMatchers(HEALTH_CHECK_PATH).permitAll()
  }
}
```

The web application then has:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig  {

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain config(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.apply(new WebberWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter());
  http
      .authorizeHttpRequests()
      .requestMatchers("/", "/request-info", "/test").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated();
  return http.build();
}
```

}

This throws the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure requestMatchers after anyRequest
```

Presumably because Spring is trying to configure the `.requestMatchers(HEALTH_CHECK_PATH).permitAll()` line *after* the `.anyRequest().authenticated();` line, despite it being specified first in the config.

How do I get Spring to configure all the upstream library config first, *before* applying the custom config from the web application itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an antMatcher() method instead of anyRequest().

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig  {

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain config(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.apply(new WebberWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter());
  http
      .authorizeHttpRequests()
      .requestMatchers("/", "/request-info", "/test").permitAll()
      .requestMatchers("/**").authenticated();
  return http.build();
}
```

Comment: you can't configure any matchers after anyRequest,Maybe use a workaround